# Retrieve suggested code alternatives in Visual Studio (possibly Resharper)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I'm not certain if this is a Resharper question or a Visual Studio question. I had a for loop in my code and the lightbulb appeared offering code suggestions; change to foreach or change to LINQ. I clicked on one to see what it did and then undid the change. How do I get those suggestions back again? Is there a keyboard shortcut? I can't find anything obvious in the Resharper menu.

Comment: for me it's alt + enter but not sure if that works for you and if that is what you mean but try it and see:-)

Comment: alt+enter works the first time, i.e.shows me the suggestions, but doesn't appear to return once I've selected an option and then undone it. It seems "one and done"

Answer (score 0):

For Resharper these are the usual shortcuts that I use: 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - Show action list
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - Refactor this

For Visual Studio see http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

However, usually only Resharper or Visual Studio shortcuts are enabled. 
Go to the ReSharper Menu entry -> Options... -> Keyboard & Menus 
There you can see if the Visual Studio refactorings are overridden by ReSharper and what keyboard scheme is used

Comment: If I select one refactoring and then change my mind, how do I get the suggestions back again?